# Scrapy ImportError: No module named project.settings when using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, scrapy, popen

I have scrapy crawler scraping thru sites. On some occasions scrapy kills itself due to RAM issues. I rewrote the spider such that it can be split and run for a site.

After the initial run, I use subprocess.Popen to submit the scrapy crawler again with new start item.

But I am getting error

`ImportError: No module named shop.settingsTraceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/kumar/envs/ishop/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module> execute() 
File "/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 109, in execute settings = get_project_settings() 
File "/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 60, in get_project_settings settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project') 
File "/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 109, in setmodule module = import_module(module) 
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module __import__(name)ImportError: No module named shop.settings`

The subprocess cmd is

`newp = Popen(comm, stderr=filename, stdout=filename, cwd=fp, shell=True)`

- comm - 
  `source /home/kumar/envs/ishop/bin/activate && cd /home/kumar/projects/usg/shop/spiders/../.. && /home/kumar/envs/ishop/bin/scrapy crawl -a category=laptop -a site=newsite -a start=2 -a numpages=10 -a split=1 'allsitespider'`
- cwd - **/home/kumar/projects/usg**

I checked sys.path and it is correct `['/home/kumar/envs/ishop/bin', '/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib64/python27.zip', '/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib64/python2.7', '/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/home/kumar/envs/ishop/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`

But looks like the import statement is using `"/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py"` instead of my virtual env.

Where am I wrong? Help please?

Comment: You need to set `env`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am doing that in the Popen command, ** source /home/kumar/envs/ishop/bin/activate **. And the sys.path (in the question) output before the error confirms that env was actually set.

Comment: so something like `env=os.environ.copy()` makes no difference?

Comment: Have tried that as well no luck. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the settings in not being loaded properly. One solution would be to build an egg and deploy it in the env before starting the crawler.

Official docs, [Eggify scrapy project](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.7/topics/scrapyd.html#deploying-your-project)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be related, let me try that and will let u know

Comment: Thanks for the doc link, I explored the docs and decided to use scrapyd instead my own shell script. That solved the problem. Though this is not a direct answer to the question, the suggestion led to alternate solution, hence marking it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest let python focus on the scrape task and use something else for process control. If it were me, I'd write a small bash script to run your program.

Test that the launcher script works by running it with `env -i yourscript.sh` because that will make sure it runs without any inherited environment settings.

Once the bash script works correctly, including setting up virtualenv etc, you could have python run that bash script, not python. You've sidestepped any strange environment issues at that point and got yourself a pretty solid launcher script.

Even better, given you have the bash script at that point, use a "proper" process controller (daemontools, supervisor...) spin up the process, restart on crash, etc.

Comment: I believe shell=True was already doing what was suggested. Anyways tried creating Shell script and executing the shell instead within spider, same result.